# Gmail Api to get Thread gives 404 even though the thread exists in users mail box

Tags: gmail-api

Gmail API to get a thread based on threadId gives `404 Not found` error

The specific email thread that I am trying to access through API is available in User's inbox and is not deleted. The user received the email as part of  group email. The code is able to access threads where the user's email address is directly involved (From, to, CC) but unable to access threads which were received as part of group email.

My API call:

```
Thread thread = gmail.users().threads().get("me", gmailThreadId).execute();
```

produces the response:

```
{
    "code" : 404,

    "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Not Found",
        "reason" : "notFound"
    } ],

    "message" : "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: I've set up a test environment and can't reproduce this issue at all, running `gmail.users().threads().get("me", gmailThreadId).execute()` gives me all emails in the thread regardless of whether I'm in the to/from/CC for that particular mail or not. How are you getting your thread ID? If I pass an incorrect thread ID I get the same 404 response.

Comment: Try to verify if the message thread you are referring to is physically present in the inbox by using the [`Users.threads: list` try it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list#try-it). Then you can check the specific thread by supplying the needed ID of the thread from the latter call to [`Users.threads: get` try it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get#try-it). Check it out, also do take note that it requires [authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list#auth) when using the said calls.

Comment: where are you getting gmailThreadId from?

Comment: Beware that the threadID is different for each user even if it's the same email.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all your suggestions. RafaGuillermo / Jay Lee - I am getting the gmailThreadId from Streak API. I tried Users.threads: list and it did not give the threadId which I was looking for. @Andres Duarte - Your answer clarified the things. The Streak API gives gmailThreadId based on the user who added the thread and it is not the same threadId for the user with which I am running the program